# Template parameter vs function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am writing some code and realized I don't know which would be better to use. What would the benefits/drawbacks of each? I am currently using the one with the const uint16_t, because I thought templating it would expand the binary by creating unique function signatures. Thanks in advance for anyone who wants to help explain this!

```
template<typename T, uint16_t response_size>
T get_endpoint_value(const uint16_t endpoint_id)
```

**vs**

```
template<typename T, uint16_t response_size, uint16_t endpoint_id>
T get_endpoint_value()
```

**vs**

```
template<typename T>
T get_endpoint_value(serial::Serial* serial, 
const uint16_t endpoint_id, const uint16_t response_size)
```

Where `endpoint_id` is just a value that gets copied into a buffer. `response_size` is used to size a `uint_t buffer[response_size]` during a data transfer over serial.

Comment: You already have all arguments listed. If you have a huge amount of different template parameter combinations, the compiler generate more or less the same code for every of these sets which may waste your memory. BUT: If all the stuff in the function can be optimized away and inlined, the result *can* be that the code size becomes smaller. But all that depends on compiler, optimizer level and all your code complexity. The only way to see the results: Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Summary: Use function arguments unless you have a special reason not to.

If you don't know your arguments at compile time, you don't have a choice - you cannot use it at a template parameter. Let's assume you know it at compile time.

If the function is so small that the compiler inlines it, then the result is the same for both function arguments and template parameters. If not, then most likely the time spent on passing function arguments is negligible, but the effect of the code bloat caused by additional template instantiation may be important.

Now, the special reasons to prefer template parameters:

1. This may allow you to avoid dynamic memory allocation inside the function. For example, if you need a buffer with a size `response_size` which you can declare as `std::vector<char> buf(response_size);`. But, if `response_size` is a template parameter, you can declare it as `std::array<char, response_size> buf;`, avoiding dynamic memory.
2. You know about an important compile-time optimization available for compile-time constants only. For example, integer division is slow, but if the divisor is a compile-time constant, it may be replaced with a sequence of faster operations.

Answer (score -1):

The template-based version allows the compiler to `inline` the call, because the address of the function is known at compile-time. The disadvantage you **cannot change the value of the template parameters at runtime**.

So if you want to change the parameters in **runtime**, you have to use parameters and not template arguments. Note that, by **runtime**, I mean when your application is running and by **compile time** I mean when your application is compiling. I would go with templates if that is not needed in runtime and the value of `response_size`/`endpoint_id` is fixed/known at compile time